# Checking location and data services are on, Android dev

Tags: java, android

My problem is that when i check if location services and data is off, my phone does not pop up with the notification that there is no data or location access enabled, like if one of them is false, it displays the notification. This function does not work on my Huawei P8 Lite but it works on my Nexus emulator

Function to check if enabled:

```
public static boolean isServicesEnabled(Context context)
{
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean Data=false;
    boolean GPS=false;

    try
    {
        Data = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        GPS = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    catch(Exception e){return false;}
    if((Data == true) && (GPS == true))
    {
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work ?? Ignore the redundant use of booleans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this to check data service**

```
   public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {
        // There are no active networks.
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
```

**try this to check GPS enable or not**

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

**and dont for get to add permission in manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**i hope this will work in your case thanks**

Comment: Actually my problem was using the function, when it said connections are true, i displayed a message to say there was a problem.. ey

Comment: Thanks for the help!!